# How to map 'confluent.' prefixed variables to proper Docker Envs?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

Let's say I need to change `confluent.security.event.logger.exporter.kafka.topic.replicas` or `confluent.metrics.reporter.topic.replicas`.
How can I set them in my docker-compose file via ENVs?

Answer (score 1):

It's described here https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#confluent-enterprise-ak-configuration

```
For the Enterprise Kafka (cp-server) image, convert the kafka.properties file variables as below and use them as environment variables:

    Prefix with KAFKA_ for Apache Kafka.
    Prefix with CONFLUENT_ for Confluent components.
    Convert to upper-case.
    Replace a period (.) with a single underscore (_).
    Replace a dash (-) with double underscores (__).
    Replace an underscore (_) with triple underscores (___).
```

It seems like I have to use

`KAFKA_CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1`

and

`KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SECURITY_EVENT_LOGGER_EXPORTER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1`